# Hyperlink in Silverlight AccordionItem HeaderTemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight-4.0

I have created a HeaderTemplate for my accordions where I want to display a text block on one side of the header and a hyperlink on the right side. The display is working correctly, but the click event is not called when the user clicks, I'm guessing b/c the header itself is trapping the click for expand/contract.

```
    <layoutToolkit:Accordion>
        <layoutToolkit:AccordionItem IsSelected="True">
            <layoutToolkit:AccordionItem.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="20">
                        <TextBlock Margin="0,0,700,0">Cancel Postcards</TextBlock>                                  
                          <HyperlinkButton Content="Next Call" Foreground="Blue" Click="NextCancel_Click" />
                      </StackPanel>
                  </DataTemplate>
            </layoutToolkit:AccordionItem.HeaderTemplate>
..... more code ....
```

Is there a way to get the hyperlink to respond to events without practically creating a new control?

Update: It looks like the header sets all child controls to disabled when expanded which is why the link doesnt work. It will work when you collapse that accordionitem. So, the question now is, how do i prevent the hyperlink from being disabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey Charlie, I just happened to answer this same question for Epic720.  You have to change the Locked VisualState.

[Interactive items in Silverlight Accordion Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696963/interactive-items-in-silverlight-accordion-header/4701587#4701587)

Here is the LockedStates VisualStateGroup of the AccordionItem which you should alter.  I can post the whole style if you need, though it's quite verbose.

```
<VisualStateGroup x:Name="LockedStates">
    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
    <VisualState x:Name="Locked">
        <Storyboard>
            <!--
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsEnabled" Storyboard.TargetName="ExpanderButton">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="False"/>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            -->
        </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
    <VisualState x:Name="Unlocked">
        <Storyboard>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsEnabled" Storyboard.TargetName="ExpanderButton">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="True"/>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
</VisualStateGroup>
```